# What rules guarantees that a variance is always positive?

Tags: probability

Page 74 in [pattern recognition and machine learning (free)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) gives the equation

$$\text{var}_\theta[\theta]\,=\,\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{D}[\text{var}_\theta[\theta\mid \mathcal{D}]] + \text{var}_{\mathcal{D}}[\mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta\mid \mathcal{D}]],\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(2.24)$$
and claims that the prior variance of $\theta$ (the term on the left-hand side, $\operatorname{var}_\theta[\theta]$) is always a positive quantity.

Could someone give a clue to what rules guarantee this property?

Comment: squares of real numbers are non-negative

Comment: How would you define the variance in question? The "rules" will be implicit in that definition if the definition is any good.

Comment: Recall that the variance of a random variable $X$ is defined as $$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E[X])^2]. $$ If this quantity is zero, then $X=\mathbb E[X]$ with probability one; that is, $X$ is a degenerate random variable.

Answer (score 4):

A good way to see this is through Jensen's Inequality:

> If $g(x)$ is convex, then $g(E[X])\leq E[g(X)]$.

Since $x^2$ is convex, $\,E[X^2] \geq E[X]^2$, and we know that $$\text{Var}[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2.$$

Thus, $\text{Var}[X] \geq 0$.

---

Note: As pointed out in the comments, $\text{Var}[X]$ can be $0$ iff $X=c$.
Proof: [If $Var(X)=0$ then is $X$ a constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990009/if-varx-0-then-is-x-a-constant)

Comment: $Var(X)\geq 0$ since $X=c$, for some constant $c$, almost surely, will provoke $Var(X)=0$

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for the observation, I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Let X be a discrete random variable with $p(\cdot)$ as pmf.

Since $\Big(x-E(X)\Big )^2\geq0$ , $p(x)\geq$ for all $x\in X$.

So we have $$V(X)=E \Big [\Big (X-E(X)\Big )^2\Big]=\sum_{x\in X} \Big (x-E(X)\Big )^2p(x)\geq0 .$$