# Proof using Markov's or Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with $E(X)=E(X^2)=0$.
By using either  Markov's or Chebyshev's inequality, show that $P(X=0)=1$.

I am unsure how to approach this question.

Comment: Well, what is the Variance of $X$?

Comment: the variance would be 0

Comment: So, that already implies $X$ is constant, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990009/if-varx-0-then-is-x-a-constant) for instance.  No need for any sort of machinery.

Comment: Yes but the question I have states that I must use Markov's or Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: Well, Chebyshev  (at least the standard form of it) doesn't really apply, since it requires non-zero variance.  The use of Markov is straight forward, if unnecessary.  Just write out what it says.

Comment: You need neither $E(X) = 0$ nor discreteness. $P(X = 0) = 1$ follows from $E(X^2) = 0$ only.

Answer (score 2):

$P(|X| >\epsilon)=P(X^{2} >\epsilon^{2}) \leq \frac 1 {\epsilon^{2}} EX^{2}=0$ for every $\epsilon >0$. This implies $P(X \neq 0)=0$.

However this result is more appropriately proved using basic facts about integrals instead of Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: Could you explain the motivation behind each of these steps or explain where the X^2 came from?

Comment: @Daisy123 Apply [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) to $X^2$.

Comment: so would it be the same thing to use X and epsilon