# Zero covariance implies constancy

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a positive random variable and $g$ be a measurable function. If we have:
$$\mathrm{Cov}(X,g(X)|X>u)=0,\ \forall u\ge0,$$
does this imply $g=\mathrm{constant}$ ?

If $X$ has absolutely continuous law then differentiating both sides of the equation w.r.t $u$ yields:
$$g(u)=\mathbb{E}[g(X)|X>u],\ \forall u\ge0$$
$$\iff g=\mathrm{constant}.$$

Does the assertion hold in general ? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990009/if-varx-0-then-is-x-a-constant