# Show that the maximum likelihood estimator is consistent

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $Y \sim \mathcal{B}(n,\theta)$. Show that the estimator $\hat{\theta}(Y) = Y/n$ is consistent. The hint says to use the Central Limit Theorem and the mean and variance formulas for the binomial distribution.

I have to show that the following expression is equal to zero:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}_\theta\bigg(\bigg\Vert \frac{Y}{n} - \theta\bigg\Vert > \varepsilon\bigg).
$$

But I am unsure how to use the hint to continue from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As I commented recently somewhere, this is the Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: @Henry I see how you can show it using the Law of Large Numbers, however I'm trying to show it using the CLT as the hint suggests

Comment: OK.  What is the mean and variance of $Y$? What does the Central Limit Theorem say?

Comment: The mean is $\mathbb{E}[Y] = n\theta$ and the variance is $\text{Var}[Y] = n\theta(1 - \theta)$. The CLT states that the distribution of the sample mean approaches a normal distribution as the sample size increases.

Comment: No it does not: the distribution of the sample mean in some senses converges to a point $\theta$ and indeed the question asks you to prove that.  Here the CLT says $\sqrt{n}( \frac Yn - \theta)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,\theta(1-\theta))$, which is not the same thing.  You already knew the expectation  of $\frac Yn$ is $\theta$ and the variance of  $\frac Yn$ is $\frac1n\theta(1-\theta)$; that variance of the sample mean  is reducing towards $0$, and you could try to use that.

Comment: @Henry Thank you. Could you maybe elaborate on how the CLT says that? The statement of the CLT I'm familiar with concerns only the distribution of the sample mean of i.i.d. random variables, I think there is something I'm missing.

Comment: One important feature of the CLT is the rescaling (and relocation)

Answer (score 1):

With $\hat \theta_n \mathrel {:=} Y/n$, here are three quick ways to solve this problem:

- From the comments you already know that $\mathbb E_\theta[\hat \theta_n] = \theta$ and $\mathbb V_\theta[\hat \theta_n] = \theta (1-\theta)/n$ for all $\theta \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}.$
  Therefore, $\mathbb E_\theta[(\hat \theta_n - \mathbb E_\theta[\hat \theta_n])^2] =  \mathbb V_\theta[\hat \theta_n] = \theta (1-\theta)/n \overset{n \to \infty} {\longrightarrow} 0$, i.e., $\hat \theta_n$ converges in $L^2$ to $\theta$ as $n \to \infty$. Use the [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4) between convergence in $L^2$ and convergence in probability to finish the proof.
- Represent $Y$ as $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$ with $X_i \overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \mathrm{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}, i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}.$
  Then, use the [weak LLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) to conclude that $\hat \theta_n \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} \theta$ as $n \to \infty.$
- If $\theta \in \{0,1\}$, then  $\mathbb V_\theta[\hat \theta_n] = 0$ [and](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/990009/888847) $\hat \theta_n = \mathbb E_\theta[\hat \theta_n] = \theta$ almost surely. You can use the [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4) between almost sure convergence and convergence in probability to conclude that $\hat \theta_n$ is also weakly consistent.
  For $\theta \in (0,1)$, again, write $Y$ as $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$ with $X_i \overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \mathrm{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}, i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}.$
  The [Lindeberg-Lévy CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) gives
  $
  \sqrt{n}\left(\hat \theta_n - \theta\right) \overset{d}{\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow} \mathop{\mathcal N}\left(0, \theta\left(1-\theta\right)\right).
  $
  To show that this implies that $\hat \theta_n$ converges in distribution (or, [equivalently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4), in probability) to $\theta$ as $n$ tends to infinity, you can rewrite $\hat \theta_n$ as follows
  $$
  \hat \theta_n = \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}_{{\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow}0} \underbrace{\sqrt{n}\left(\hat \theta_n - \theta\right)}_{\overset{d}{\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow} \mathop{\mathcal N}\left(0, \theta\left(1-\theta\right)\right)} + \theta.
  $$
  Now, use [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem#Statement) to finish the proof:
  $$
  \hat \theta_n \overset{d}{\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow} 0 + \theta = \theta 
  \iff \hat \theta_n \overset{p}{\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow} \theta.
  $$