# Zero variance Random variables with density

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance

I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786003/zero-variance-random-variables)
the question:

> Can a random variable have a density function whose variance  is $0$ ?

I understood as a random variable which has a density.

What is your opinion on what I understood and if that is the case on the answer that was given  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786003/zero-variance-random-variables)

Comment: What about the old question/answers didn't address your confusion?

Comment: @jameselmore : If $X$ is a r.v. with density $f$, then $p(X=m)=\int_m^m f(t) dt=0$. Is'nt true ?

Comment: @Did This question appear to be aware of the duplicate, but the OP wants to know if a density exists for an almost surely constant random variable. Seems sufficiently different to me.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 A deliberate dup is still a dup, no?

Comment: @Did what I meant was that the question was aware of the question, but the objective in each seems different.

Comment: @ Eupraxis1981 : This is exactly what I wanted for my question. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to the extent that you let the Dirac delta function act as a density, then yes. An RV with zero variance is *almost surely* constant, so its just a degenerate discrete random variable.