# Variance zero => symmetry?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have a random variable $X$ with variance zero. Does this imply that the distribution of $X$ is symmetric? I would say yes, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786003/zero-variance-random-variables

Comment: Is a constant r.v. a symmetric distribution @Chou?

Comment: Why do you use a statement like "a random variable $X$ with variance zero" if you understand that $X = c$ a.s.? The setup is totally unrelated to your question, which is also unclear; what is your definition of symmetric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say $X(\omega)=k,\forall k \in \Omega$ then $X=k$ *surely*.

However, we have to define your question a little more. X's CDF is certainly not symmetric, $F_X(-a)\neq F_X(a)$, but its probability measure is symmetric ($P(X=-a)=P(X=a)=0,\forall a\neq k$) and $P(X=k)=1$. So its symmetric about $k$.

However, if $X=k$ *almost surely* (for example, its a mixed-distribution) then its distribution need not be symmetric: for the density portion, we can always define a null set $\mathcal{N}$ on $\Omega:f_X(\cdot)$ such that $\forall x \in \mathcal{N}, f_X(x)\neq f_X(-x)\text{ and } f(|x|)<\infty$ but this will not affect the probabilities.

So, it depends on what you mean by distribution. I think the answer is yes.

Comment: First you acknowledge that $X$ cannot be anything but a constant, write down a measure which is singular with respect to Lebesgue, and then decide $X$ could be continuous? ...

Comment: @snarski I clarified my two cases.

Comment: Europraxis, I didn't want to go into probability theory since I don't much about it... So, my thought is only true for a discrete domain, but not a continuum, right?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. ok, staying away from silly theoretical examples, the answer is yes...if someone told you the variance of a rv were zero, you should act as if its symmetric about its constant value. I was just bringing up theoretical nuances that, frankly, don't really matter in the real world.