# Can random variable $X$ take $2$ (or more values) in this situation?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, variance

I am looking at the following exercise in a text. "Let $a$ be a real number and $X$ be a discrete random variable such that $Var(X)  = 0$. Which statement is not always true?".

Then it gives a list of statements, where the first statement is "$X$ takes only one value". The answer given in the text says that one other statement is not always true (I am not bothering to write that statement here, but it involves number $a$).

But, surely the statement above is also not always true. For example let $X$ take values $0$ and $1$, with $P(X = 0) = 0$ and $P(X=1) = 1$. Then $Var(X)=0$. So this means there is a mistake in the text I am reading?

Comment: Your text is correct if the sample space of $X$ is finite, because then _taking on a value with probability $0$_ is the same as _not taking at all_, and the claim follows by the definition of variance and the trivial inequality (sum of squares is $0$ iff all elements are $0$) and $X$ takes only one value with probability $1$

Comment: I believe one can construct as many examples as one wants of $X$ with more than one value, taking on non-trivial probability distribution, which would invalidate the statement of the text, right? I only chose my example since it's easiest to construct...@PrasunBiswas

Comment: Since random variables are functions, we can come up with random variables taking as many values as we wish regardless of probabilities. In this respect, I would say that the quoted statement is ill-designed and subject to misinterpretation. The statement would have been absolutely correct if it were formulated as "$X$ takes only one value with probability one".

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\o}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$

For a discrete random variable, "taking a value with probability $0$" is the same as not taking on that value at all. That is not the case for continuous RVs and the terms "almost never"/ "almost surely" come into play for events (or complement of event) with infinitesimally small probability.

If $X$ is a discrete RV with a finite sample space, then your textbook is correct in saying that $X$ takes only one value (a more precise way would be to say *$X$ takes only one value with probability $1$*)

$$\o{Var}(X):=\Bbb E[(X-\mu)^2]=\sum_x (x-\mu)^2\cdot\Bbb P(X=x)$$

Now, both $\Bbb P(X=x)$ and $(x-\mu)^2$ are non-negative for all $x$, so $\o{Var}(X)\ge 0$ with equality iff all the terms in the sum are $0$ which is only when $x=\mu,\Bbb P(X=\mu)=1$ and all other values $X$ can "potentially take" has probability $0$ (in a setting with finite sized sample space, this is the same as not taking on that value at all)

So, if the sample space for $X$ is finite, $X$ takes only one value $\mu$ (which will also be its mean) with probability $1$ and doesn't take on any other value (takes with probability $0$)

---

Now that I think about it, the same should hold for countably infinite sized sample space as well.

Suppose $X$ takes on values $(x_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ with probabilities $(p_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$. Denote by $\mu$ the mean of $X$. Then, by definition (and law of the unconscious statistician),

$$\o{Var}(X):=\Bbb E[(X-\mu)^2]=\sum_i (x_i-\mu)^2p_i$$

If only finitely many $p_i$'s are nonzero, the terms with zero probabilities vanish and we come back to the case of finite sized sample space.

Suppose countably infinitely many $p_i$'s are nonzero. There is at least one $x_k\ne\mu$ with probability $p_k\ne 0$. But then, $\o{Var}(X)\ge (x_k-\mu)^2p_k\gt 0$ which is a contradiction to $\o{Var}(X)=0$

In conclusion, your textbook is correct.

Comment: Thank you. What happens for a discrete random variable where sample space is infinite? @Prasun Biswas

Comment: @Sasha1001: I updated my answer. I also suspect the last argument is sufficient and that _any_ random variable $X$ with zero variance is necessarily constant.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/786003/215900) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is right. In probability theory, we sometime omit the phrase "almost surely" ("almost everywhere" in real analysis). So the text could also be regarded right as "$X$ takes only one value (almost surely/everwhere)".

Comment: I don't understand. I believe one can construct as many other examples as one wants such that $X$ takes more than value but $Var(X) = 0$, right? Which invalidates the statement? @DreamAR

Comment: P.S. This is an introductory text on probability which does not assume any knowledge of measure theory, and phrases like "almost surely" have no relevance here. @DreamAR

Comment: @Sasha1001 OK, so your carefulness is correct. The introductory text just want to say that $X$ almost takes one value, and the possibility of taking other values is zero, i.e. *impossible to happen*. There can be many other value, of course, but the possibility of taking them is zero.

Comment: In that case, how can one prove that if $Var(X) = 0$, then $X$ MUST take only $1$ value?, or rather, as you say, possibility of other values must be zero? @ DreamAR

Comment: @Sasha1001 You cannot prove $X$ **must** take one value, just like your example. However take $X$ to be your example and $Y$ takes only one value, then you cannot distiguish $X$ and $Y$ in probability theory. Everything like expectation, variance is same between $X$ and $Y$. So we can consider $X=Y$ and say $X$ also takes only one value. Adding a phrase "almost surely" is always correct, if you like.